# How to select between two lines like Matlab in Vim?

Tags: python, matlab, vim, neovim

In Matlab, there is a way to select code between two predefined typed markers. I want to replicate the same thing on Python using `##` as the block marker. For example, let's say the cursor is in `Block 2` on the variable `y1`:

```
## Block 1
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


## Block 2
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4, 100)

y1 = np.sin(x)  # <== My cursor is here
y2 = np.cos(x)  
y3 = np.tan(x)

## Block 3
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

I would like to yank the following block into my register

```
## Block 2
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi*4, 100)

y1 = np.sin(x)  # <== My cursor is here
y2 = np.cos(x)  
y3 = np.tan(x)
```

===============================================

Edit 1: I have searched all over stackoverflow, and I couldn't find anybody asking a similar question. Most of it is how to select functions or classes in python. I know it's possible because I found a plugin that does do this action, [wmvanvliet/jupyter-vim](https://github.com/wmvanvliet/jupyter-vim) (see the first thing on the readme for a video of it working). But it's a full on REPL and it adds 200ms to my start up time.

I'm sure there is a simple vim way to do this. I just can't find it

Comment: That certainly seems possible in vim. What have you tried so far? See https://stackoverflow.com/tour, which says "Don't ask about questions you haven't tried to find an answer for (show your work!)".

Comment: Yeah, it seems like an easy enough thing to do. I have been searching for the past week, but I cannot find it. I will edit my comment to "show my work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

`/^##` to find the block start and end locations.

If your cursor is in the middle, you can use `N` to go to the previous hit (i.e., the start of the block), press `v` to enter visual mode, and hit `n` to go to the next block start. Since you don't want to yank the next block start, you'll need to move up a line with `k` (there are other ways, but this works nicely since you have an empty line between blocks anyway).

Putting it all together:

```
/^##<CR>Nvnk
```

will select the block your cursor is in.

You can make this into a function or a macro, if that's too many characters to type. [Here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Macros) is a good tutorial on how to put commands together into a macro. If we wanted to make a macro and save it in register b (for block, I guess?), we could do

```
qb/^##<CR>Nvnkq
```

and execute the macro with `@b`.